# bash getopts validate options

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, command-line-arguments, getopts

I have following code in `bash` script:

```
# argument validation and usage help
usage()
{
cat << EOF
usage: $0 options

File Integrity Monitoring Script:

OPTIONS:
   -b      input file for [backup]
   -r      input file for [diff report]
   -l      list backup files
EOF
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    usage
    exit 0
fi


while getopts ":b:r:l:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        b)
            B=${OPTARG}
            backup $B
            ;;
        r)
            R=${OPTARG}
            diffcheck $R
            ;;
        l)
            ls -ld /root/backup/* | awk -F/ '{print $(NF)}'
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            exit 0
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

## Question:

if use option `-b` it required `inputfile` but `-l` it just need to print list of directories without passing any argument, is there any simple way to find out which option need `argument` ?

```
spatel # ./final.sh -l
usage: ./final.sh options

File Integrity Monitoring Script:

OPTIONS:
   -b      input file for [backup]
   -r      input file for [diff report]
   -l      list backup files
```

if i pass any argument it works

```
spatel # ./final.sh -l xxx
May-06-15-10-03
May-06-15-10-04
May-06-15-10-19
May-06-15-11-30
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but the `:` after an option flag in the `getopts` string means "needs an argument" to `getopts`. (The `:` at the very start of the string means something else entirely.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` following an option in the argument to `getopts` indicates that it takes an argument. Since `-l` doesn't require an option, you should instead use

```
getopts getopts ":b:r:l"
```

Comment: holy cow!!! that was easy... i was thinking `:` is required to separate options... Thanks for help

Comment: So what happens if you have 2 with and 2 without? `":b:r:l :x" ? x needs the colon before it but that means l will have one after it.....so im confused

Comment: br: would mean b does NOT have an option but r does.